# Zend Form add img to Label in dt

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

my mind is twisting about the decorators. Slowly i get it all but i have 1 other issue.

Im adding spans to the dds, now i want to add a image inside the dt that it looks like this

```
 <dt><img></img><label></label></dt>
```

Or can the image be placed inside the label? 
Can the image be placed inside the dt in general ?

My actual code is

```
$oElement->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array( array('data' => 'HtmlTag' ),
        array( 'tag' => 'span' ) ),
    array( array('span'   => 'HtmlTag' ),
        array( 'tag' => 'dd', 'class' => $class ) ),
    array( 'Label', array( 'tag' => 'dt', 'class' => $class ) ),
));
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: If the image is purely decorative, can you do this with CSS instead?

Comment: how can i get this work via css? set the dt background?

Comment: i managed to solve this with a picture as background for the dt.